# Regex split the string at \n but skip the first one if it is \n\n

Tags: python, regex

I want to split some strings on Python by separating at \n and use them in that format, but some of those strings have unexpected newlines and I want to ignore them.

TO CLARIFY: Both examples have only one string.

For example this is a regular string with no unexpected newlines:

```
Step 1
Cut peppers into strips.
Step 2
Heat a non-stick skillet over medium-high heat. Add peppers and cook on stove top for about 5 minutes.
Step 3
Toast the wheat bread and then spread hummus, flax seeds, and spinach on top
Step 4
Lastly add the peppers. Enjoy!
```

but some of them are like this:

```
Step 1
Using a fork, mash up the tuna really well until the consistency is even.

Step 2
Mix in the avocado until smooth.

Step 3
Add salt and pepper to taste. Enjoy!
```

I have to say I am new at regex and if the solution is obvious, please forgive

Edit: Here is my regex

```
    stepOrder = []
    # STEPS
    txtSteps = re.split("\n",directions.text)
    listOfLists = [[] for i in range(len(txtSteps)) if i % 2 == 0]
    for i in range(len(listOfLists)):
        listOfLists[i] = [txtSteps[i*2],txtSteps[i*2+1]]
    recipe["steps"] = listOfLists
    print(listOfLists)
```

directions.text is every one of these examples I gave. I can share what it is too, but I think it's irrelevant.

Comment: what is your desired output? I don't quite understand which newlines are "ok" and which ones are to ignore

Comment: It's completely fine being new to regex. Though can you share your regex?

Comment: @Rabinzel Some strings I am splitting have 2 "\n"s after the description. Like I expect them to be "Step 1\nUsing a fork, mash up the tuna really well until the consistency is even.\nStep 2\n....."

but on the second example it is:
"Step 1\nUsing a fork, mash up the tuna really well until the consistency is even.\n\nStep 2\n....."

I want regex to split it like the first example, simply I want it to skip the first \n if they are ordered as \n\n

I don't expect a "\n\n\n" so it shouldn't be a problem but if they are then I'm going to need to take only the last \n

Comment: Try using `"\n(\n)?"` inside `re.split("\n",directions.text)`.

Comment: @lemon can you explain, it didn't split like it should do on a fine string like the first example and I got a list index out of range error

("\n(\n)?",directions.text) did I write it wrong

Comment: Does my solution below work for you?

Comment: I couldn't test it with problemed ones yet, the strings are coming randomly. But I asked for something else, can you look at it too please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by splitting on the following regex:

```
(?<=\d\n).*
```

Basically it will get any character in the same line `.*` which is preceeded by one digit `\d` and one new line character `\n`.

Check the regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/IY1N5m/1).

---

Your whole Python snippet then becomes simplified as follows using the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method:

```
# STEPS
steps = re.findall("(?<=\d\n).*", directions.text)
out = [[{'order':i+1, 'step': step}] for i, step in enumerate(steps)]
```

Comment: I want to save the orders in the list as well, but this only saves the steps' descriptions. I don't understand what your code does so I can't alter it to do that, can you help me on that part too?

I want to save it as to be clear:  [ ["Step 1", "Cut peppers into strips."], ["Step 2",.............]]

Comment: If your steps are always ordered ascendently, `re.findall` will get your steps in an ordered way. It seems highly redundant to save "Step 1", "Step 2", ecc... as lists are ordered structures of elements (unlike sets). Why would you prefer that? If you really need to get back your numbered values, you can always iterate like this: `for i, el in enumerate(recipe["steps"]): print('Step '+i, el)`

Comment: probably, but that's how my teammate asked me to do. Well, my code isn't how he expects it to be either, it should've been: [ [ {'order': 1, 'step': Cut peppers into strips.} ].......}]] but I made a mistake there I think

Comment: thanks I'll change it right-away. I would vote you, but I guess I need reputation for that. Please know I appreciate your helps. And update here when I test it.

Comment: I've added code to generate your dictionaries. Check the updated answer. Consider ticking this solution as the one that solves your problem

Comment: you're fantastic man, thanks it works perfectly. And your code is only 2 lines, it really amazes me. I just changed out with recipe["steps"] and voilà THANK YOU SO MUCH ! Really hope to see you in my future problems haha

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open("your_file_name")
content = f.read()
f.close()

for line in content.split("\n"):
    if re.match("^&",line):
        continue
    print(line)
```